# how to remove table border line in dita?

Tags: dita

I got a question related to dita.
It's a sample for dita below that i searched on web.

```
<body>
    <table frame="topbot">
        <tgroup cols="2">
            <colspec colname="COLSPEC0" colwidth="121*" />
            <colspec colname="COLSPEC1" colwidth="76*" />
            <thead>
                <row>
                    <entry colname="COLSPEC0" valign="top">Animal</entry>
                    <entry colname="COLSPEC1" valign="top">Gestation</entry>
                </row>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <row>
                    <entry>Elephant (African and Asian)</entry>
                    <entry>19-22 months</entry>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <entry>Giraffe</entry>
                    <entry>15 months</entry>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <entry>Rhinoceros</entry>
                    <entry>14-16 months</entry>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <entry>Hippopotamus</entry>
                    <entry>7 1/2 months</entry>
                </row>
            </tbody>
        </tgroup>
    </table>
</body>
```

I looked forward to see table that has no border line since there was attribute frame="topbot". as far as i know, the attribute removes all border line on table except only top and bottom line. but result has all border lines.

So, which part is wrong ? why does frame="topbot" attribute not work ?

Thanks

Comment: As far I can see, there is nothing wrong with the example. Tested this and "topbot" works as it should (top & bottom line only visible) at XML editor. If the example was at the web page, maybe cascading style sheets at the web page make those borders?

Comment: Thanks for opinion. I resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem.

It needs colsep="0" rowsep="0" attribute as below.

```
<body>
    <table frame="topbot">
        <tgroup cols="2" colsep="0" rowsep="0">
            <colspec colnum="1" colname="1" colwidth="61*"/>
            <colspec colnum="2" colname="2" colwidth="39*"/>
            <thead>
                <row rowsep="0">
                    <entry colname="1">Animal</entry>
                    <entry colname="2">Gestation</entry>
                </row>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <row rowsep="0">
                    <entry colname="1">Elephant (African and Asian)</entry>
                    <entry colname="2">19-22 months</entry>
                </row>
                <row rowsep="0">
                    <entry colname="1">Giraffe</entry>
                    <entry colname="2">15 months</entry>
                </row>
                <row rowsep="0">
                    <entry colname="1">Rhinoceros</entry>
                    <entry colname="2">14-16 months</entry>
                </row>
                <row rowsep="0">
                    <entry colname="1">Hippopotamus</entry>
                    <entry colname="2">7 1/2 months</entry>
                </row>
            </tbody>
        </tgroup>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you know remove borders from table attribute xslt?

Comment: @WhoAmI In table-attr.xsl file find this code `table__tableframe__all`. Here add attr set `border-before-width , border-after-width, border-end-width, border-start-width`make these as `0pt`.

Comment: This is not the right solution, `topbot` adds top and bottom borders.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `frame="none"` to remove all borders. See https://tdg.docbook.org/tdg/4.5/table.html for other possible values (FYI: DITA uses the same table format as Docbook).

```xml
<table frame="none">
...
</table>
```